# Hp Laserjet 4350tn Printing problem

Tags: printing

I got a problem here, hp printer with connection to jet direct via serial port 1, which connects to router , the problem is I can see the printer on the network but cannot print out anything, means it reads the printer but it shows document as queue, any body has a clue how to fix this problem, help is appreciated much.

Comment: When adding the printer after the IP address you must have a port number ex x.x.x.x:X work right away, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add

:then port number
like--->`:1`